# CLLocation distanceFromLocation result is differ when I calculate

Tags: ios, objective-c, distance, core-location, cllocation

I have used CLLocation's distanceFromLocation: method to calculate distance from some location.

But it's result is slightly different when I calculate by using "Haversine formula".

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)fromCoord {
  double earthRadius = 6371.0; // Earth's radius in Kilometers

  // Get the difference between our two points then convert the difference into radians
  double nDLat = RADIANS((fromCoord.latitude - self.coordinate.latitude));
  double nDLon = RADIANS((fromCoord.longitude - self.coordinate.longitude));

  double fromLat = RADIANS(self.coordinate.latitude);
  double toLat =  RADIANS(fromCoord.latitude);

  double nA = pow ( sin(nDLat/2.0), 2 ) + cos(fromLat) * cos(toLat) * pow ( sin(nDLon/2.0), 2 );

  double nC = 2.0 * atan2( sqrt(nA), sqrt( 1 - nA ));
  double nD = earthRadius * nC;

  return nD * 1000.0;
}


CLLocation * loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[location.latitude doubleValue]
                                                           longitude:[location.longitude doubleValue]];

CLLocationDistance dist = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:loc];
CLLocationDistance dist2 = [userLocation distanceFromCoordinate:loc.coordinate];
```

Why two values are different?

Should I init location object with horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make `distanceFromLocation` match the Haversine formula? I'm running into this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are different because you are using different code.

You don't say how different. 
Totally different? There's a bug in your code.
Big differences for places close together? Maybe your formula has problems with rounding errors. 
Differences that grow as places are further apart? Maybe your definition of distance is different. Should be the closest distance on a path along earth surface.

In general, Earth is not a sphere but a spheroid. Taking that into account is more difficult but gives more precise results.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly different because **Earth's Radius** is not exact *6371 km*. Use the correct Earth's radius, may be you can get better results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official WGS84 earth radius:
6 378 137 meter

I remember that ios delivers exactly the same result.

> Should I init location object with horizontalAccuracy and
>   verticalAccuracy?

No, for sure not. That attributes are hints how acurate the position might be.
Distance is calculated by latitude and longitude only.

There are not much formulas:
 - haversine formula (a bit slower than law of cosines, otherwise fine)
 - law of cosines (problematic on small distances if not using 64 bit precision)
 - vicenties which i smore acurate, it uses an elipsoidal earth model.

Comment: I calculated earth radius with distance of distanceFromLocation: method and above formula.

Result seems weird because I got two result.
`6367.150394`
`6381.907010`

I think apple does not use "Haversine formula" and they have their own algorithm. So I have to find another formula or just use it.

Comment: Is that 6367.15 meters or km? Just use it will work, try closer realistic distances. Then the difference is a thousandstel of a milimeter. However there are not much formulas: Greater Circle, Haversine and Vicenties.

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same problem... so i used google webservice to calculate distance. use this method, you will get accurate distance

```
-(void)calculateDistance()
{
//http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.742964,-87.995971&   destination=41.811511,-87.967923&mode=driving&sensor=false
NSString *LocationUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@,%@&destination=%@,%@&mode=driving&sensor=false",origin.latitude,origin.longitude,destination.latitude,destination.latitude];
NSLog(@"Location URL:%@",LocationUrl);

NSURL *finalurl = [NSURL URLWithString: LocationUrl];

NSLog(@"Final URL = %@",finalurl);

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalurl];
NSLog(@"Data:-%@",data);
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data       
options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// NSLog(@"josn data of location:%@",[json description]);
NSMutableDictionary *routes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
NSMutableArray *legs = [routes valueForKey:@"legs"];
NSMutableDictionary *newDistance =[legs valueForKey:@"distance"];
NSMutableArray distanceList =[[newDistance valueForKey:@"text"]objectAtIndex:0];
distance = [[distanceList objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.1f",distance);
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I agree with @AlexWien

Comment: Additionally, I believe this answer is talking about the _driving_ distance while the question is talking about _straight line_ distance.